# how to get specific column's data as list from object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, object

suppose we have the following json data

```
var example = [{
    latitude: 11.1111,
    longitude: 111.111,
    name: "for example1",
    altitude: 88
},
{
    latitude: 22.2222,
    longitude: 222.222,
    name: "for example2",
    altitude: 89
},
{
    latitude: 33.3333,
    longitude: 333.333,
    name: "for example3",
    altitude: 90
}
]
```

I want to get the lists(or object) that has only latitude and longitude data, because Map API in my
react-native application require them. and by some performance issues, I can't use loop.
I know that writing a separate query(MySQL) can solve this problem, but I don't think this is good solution. (If not, I will very grateful if you can tell me)

---

thank you for reading this, how can I solve this?

Comment: why not loop over every?

Comment: data size is pretty huge, loop makes my application slow terribly...
Is loop the best way?

Comment: what happens on passing all the data

Comment: dont mutate just pass the data

Comment: you mean I should get the latitude and longitude from separate query?

Comment: oh, if you mean just pass the full data (var example), when I tried, I encountered 
some errors caused by map api that it cannot resolve "full data"

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use loop"? Do you mean that you cannot loop over the array because of some constraints? I currently understand that as: No `for`, `while`, `do-while`, `.reduce`, `.map`, `.forEach`, etc. construct can be used.

Comment: No, there isn't any contraint. I can freely use loop.
but If I tried loop over every data, I feel it is too slow to get the result.
but well... It seems like loop is the best way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this. it returns a new array with only lat/long items in objects

```html
const newArray = example.map(el => {
    return {
        latitude: el.latitude,
        longitude: el.longitude
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
example.map(({latitude, longitude}) => ({latitude, longitude}))
```

> because Map API in my react-native application require them.

Would it be satisfied with an iterator?

[edit]

```
const projected = ( function* () {
  for (record of example) yield {
    latitude:  record.latitude,
    longitude: record.longitude,
  };
})()
```

Comment: I don't know whether I understand your question correctly.
If I should use iterator,  I will create a new object through the loop statement and deliver it to the API.

Comment: Why would looping be any less performant than hitting the database again, for data you already have and all you need is a projection of them, and hitting the database again seems to be the alternative you are considering?

I don't know this API. I'm taking your word about what it requires. What you said seems to indicate that it won't take fields it doesn't know and just ignore them; it wants just latitude and longitude. You have to pass it all the records either all at once or as a stream. I don't know whether it will accept an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
example.map(item => ('latitude' && 'longitude') in item && item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to save all filtered data to your database. Am I right? If it is then you can map or loop the data first in this way ->

```
const filterdData = example.map(({latitude, longitude}) => ({latitude, longitude}));
```

And then insert bulk to MySQL database. Like this way ->

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(val1, val2, val3), (val4, val5, val6), (val7, val8, val9);
```